# Rails server start error Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a fresh Ubuntu install with ruby -v 1.9.2, rails -v 3.1.1, gem -v 1.8.10, rvm -v 1.9.0 ... & whenever I try to start a server on a hello world application I get this list of errors

```
/home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require': no such file to load -- openssl (LoadError)
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/session/cookie.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:131:in `const_get'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:131:in `session_store'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:172:in `block in default_middleware_stack'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:146:in `tap'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:146:in `default_middleware_stack'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:446:in `app'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:37:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/zyad/Desktop/rails_projects/firs_app2/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/zyad/Desktop/rails_projects/firs_app2/config.ru:4:in `require'
    from /home/zyad/Desktop/rails_projects/firs_app2/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /home/zyad/Desktop/rails_projects/firs_app2/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /home/zyad/Desktop/rails_projects/firs_app2/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:54:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
    from /home/zyad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Any idea how to fix that? Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Do you have the [OpenSSL packages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenSSL) installed?

Comment: Yes -->> when I typed openssl version
              "OpenSSL 1.0.0e 6 Sep 2011"

Comment: what about rvm pkg install openssl, see http://beginrescueend.com/packages/openssl/

Comment: This is not a "list of errors".  There is one error:  no such file to load -- openssl.  The lines below are called a stack trace and they show you exactly where the error happened in the code.

Comment: this link did the trick http://beginrescueend.com/packages/openssl/ ... thank you all for your precious help :-) !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

from the RVM [guide](http://rvm.io/packages/openssl/):

```
$ rvm pkg install openssl
$ rvm remove 1.9.2
$ rvm install 1.9.2 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

Comment: Yup, found this an hour ago & it did fix the issues ... thanks a lot mate :-) !!